# Opening map package does not display Table of Contents?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, map-package

When map packages (.mpk) that I have created with Arc 10.5.1 are subsequently opened, the map displays but the Table of Contents is blank:

[image]

But if I then click on any of the *List by...* buttons (other than List by Drawing Order), the Table of Contents now appears:

[image]

But List by Drawing Order will never display the Table of Contents:

[image]

This problem occurs with .mpks created with either the *Package Map* tool or the *File > Share As > Map Package* option.

How can I create .mpks where the Table of Contents automatically displays upon opening?

Comment: Do you have another empty data frame?

Comment: No.  There is only one data frame.